# How to keep SelectedIndex to -1 on ItemsSource change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a `Combobox` set like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding FilteredGroups} Name="cbo"/>
```

Every time the `FilteredGroups` object changes, the `SelectedIndex` goes to 0, but I need it to go to -1.  My current workaround is below, but I was curious if there is a better way to do this:

```
 ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged += (o,e) => 
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "FilteredGroups")
            _resetAdd = true;
    }

 cboOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (_resetAdd && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
         cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
     else if(!_resetAdd && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
      //Normal selection logic
     _resetAdd = false;
 }
```

I have tried to set `SelectedIndex=-1` in the XAML, as well as bind to an object on my VM that I set to null during the group change.

I am also using an ItemTemplate if that makes a difference?

Comment: It could be that SelectedItem is the leading here and that you have an actual item in your itemssource that is null. Otherwise it's a strange problem. Or try setting selecteditem to null :)

Comment: Have you tried setting up a two way binding on the `SelectedItem` property, and then setting the bound property to null whenever you change the `FilteredGroups` collection?

Comment: What type of collection is FilteredGroups?

Comment: @Blam IEnumerable....I am guessing that you suggest I try ObservableCollection?

Comment: Not sure.  What is the nature of the filter?  Do you have a static list you are filtering or is is more dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to any `DependencyProperty` when it is being changed and set it from there.

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof (ComboBox)).AddValueChanged(cb, (s, e) => { cb.SelectedIndex = -1; });
```

And don't forget to call `RemoveValueChanged` to avoid memory leaks.